# Treatment of sexual addicted person

Tags: halal-haram, quran

I am living away from my home country since last 4 years. As I live alone from a long time, usually I get anxiety and sometime depression.

And now I am addicted to sexual activities, after each week I can't control myself to go brothel for sexual satisfaction. I tried my best, everything I have tried, watched videos about it that I can get rid from it.

But nothing is working for me. I feel very guilty when  I do such kind of cheap and stupid things, but now I don't have any control. I am no longer to control myself.

I am not here to ask that it is halal or haraam, off course it is one of cheapest habit and Haram in Islam.

A lot of time I did tubah and tried not to go, but failed. I really want to come back myself on Islamic track and get rid from such kind of cheap things.

I am helpless, I can't discuss this with anyone, this is only way I can ask for help.

Kindly suggest me the ways that I can take advantage.

Please, please help.

Comment: This video may help: (https://youtu.be/GkHV7NCq7vI) and remember to apply every knowledge you receive. Sorry, I'm not qualified to help you, as I'm still a student of knowledge. It'd be better to ask a real scholar, here anyone can answer.

Comment: You need a person, could be a mentor or a spouse to accompany you in real world, limit your solitude brother, and plan to move to other country that has better society

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Siam, fasting.  One of the main benefits of Siam is learning self restraint (taqwa).  If you can conquer hunger and thirst, you can conquer any emotion including sexual desires.  You can survive without sexual activity but not without food and water.  When really hungry or thirsty the body and mind go into survival mode forcing all other emotions into suspension.

Siam was used successfully to cancel sexual desire by some brothers who encountered continuous solicitations by prostitutes when performing Muslim missionary work in Africa.  Siam will tame your "nefs" and put it on a leash. With the help of Allah, you become the master of your emotions, not the reverse.

Siam is obligatory during the month of Ramadan, but is "wajib" (recommended) at least twice a week outside of Ramadan, customarily Mondays and Thursdays.  It is a blessing and a mercy from Allah to help us to restrain our emotions.  Fast as much as you need to control your libido.

Fasting is difficult but has these great benefits mentioned.  In fact the following aya was placed by Allah right in the middle of where fasting is prescribed in the Quran.

002.186 When My servants ask thee concerning Me, I am indeed close (to them): I listen to the prayer of every suppliant when he calleth on Me: Let them also, with a will, Listen to My call, and believe in Me: That they may walk in the right way.

Wa 'Idhā Sa'alaka `Ibādī`Annī Fa'innī Qarībun ۖ 'Ujību Da`wata Ad-Dā`i 'Idhā Da`āni ۖ Falyastajībū Lī Wa Līu'uminū Bī La`allahum Yarshudūna
    وَ‌إِ‌ذَ‌ا‌ سَأَلَكَ عِبَا‌دِي عَ‍‍نِّ‍‍ي فَإِنِّ‍‍ي قَ‍‍‍ر‍ِ‍ي‍‍بٌ ۖ ‌أُج‍‍ِ‍ي‍‍بُ ‌دَعْوَةَ ‌ال‍‍دّ‍َ‍‌اعِ ‌إِ‌ذَ‌ا‌ ‌دَع‍‍َ‍انِ ۖ فَلْيَسْتَجِيبُو‌ا‌ لِي ‌وَلْيُؤْمِنُو‌ا‌ بِي لَعَلَّهُمْ يَرْشُدُ‌ونَ

This beautiful aya is the only one in the Quran where Allah sbth addresses us directly without first telling the Prophet pbuh "qul" (say).  Most likely, this is to emphasize that the dua made during Siam is particularly heard and accepted.

Also, you must "lower your gaze", which includes not viewing much of the online Internet media.  Very difficult these days, but InshAllah with Siam, you can succeed.  I hope this helps you InshAllah.

Comment: very useful, I appreciate. Thanks